# VSTO outlook post item "To" is not accessible to me

Tags: outlook-addin

I have a `PostItem` like this:

```
Outlook.PostItem pi = this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olPostItem);
pi.Save();
var sentBox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
pi.Move(sentBox);
```

the item is kept in `sentitems` folder as requested but I can't edit the recipients list (as if it was actually sent mail).

Comment: By design.  Quoting: "Unlike a MailItem object, a PostItem object is not sent to a recipient. You use the Post() method, which is analogous to the Send() method for the MailItem object, to save the PostItem to the target public folder instead of mailing it."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.postitem?view=outlook-pia

Comment: OK, so if I like to create a "sent mail item" that was not acually sent' is there another way? If not, fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a sent message? After you create the `PostItem` item (which is created in the sent state), change its `MessageClass` to `"IPM.Note"`, save it, store its entry id in a variable, release all references to it (use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`), then reopen as `MailItem` object using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`. Note that the icon will still be wrong and you will need to delete the PR_ICON_INDEX property - but `PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty` will not let you do this for that property.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option, creating a message in the sent state is as easy as

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
  set Msg = Inbox.Items.Add
  Msg.Sent = true
  set CU = Session.CurrentUser
  set recip = Msg.Recipients.AddEx("Joe The Recipient", "joe@domain.demo", "SMTP", olTo)
  Msg.Subject = "fake sent message"
  Msg.Body = "just a test"
  Msg.Sender = CU
  Msg.SentOnBehalfOf = CU
  Msg.SentOn = Now
  Msg.ReceivedTime = Now
  Msg.Save
```